# android sqlite delete database in package

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, delete-file

I used the following code

```
String destDir = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() +
            "/databases/";
    String destPath = destDir + "jobs";
    File f = new File(destPath);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        //---make sure directory exists---
        File directory = new File(destDir);
        directory.mkdirs();
        //---copy the db from the assets folder into 
        // the databases folder---
        try {
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("jobs"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {     
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) 
throws IOException {
    //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

This copies the database from the assets folder into the data/data database folder and then I can use it but only if its not there.

I need to be able to delete the file in the package and then copy the file from the assets every time the app runs.

I update the data in the database by copying a new database into the assets folder each time and unless I completely un-install the app and re install it the new data is not added.

I want to eventually load the database from a folder on the device so all the user has to do to update is replace the file and the app reads from the new file but that's for later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... just remove this line:

```
 if (!f.exists()) {
```

and its corresponding closing bracket (})

This will copy the db ALWAYS, when you run your app.
(It implicitly deletes the file for you, if it is found)